# Do redirect and add variable to URL through htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have htaccess redirect oranges.info to 
example.com/about.html?=fruit

This is my htaccess file which unfortunately is only doing the redirect and not adding the variable.  Any ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oranges.info$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oranges.info$
rewriterule ^domainfolder\/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/about\.html$1?fruit" [R=301,QSA,L] 

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule syntax isn't correct:

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oranges\.info$ [NC]
rewriterule ^ http://example.com/about.html?fruit [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test in a different browser.

Comment: Works well in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but not Chrome.  Any ideas what is needed for Chrome?